# stdev() differences between talib and pine script versions

Tags: pine-script, ta-lib

I'm trying to port a strategy from tradingview (pinescript) to a framework I built in nodejs.
My strategy uses breakouts on the Bollinger bands. in my pine script I've implemented the BBs with standard deviation ( basically copying the build-in indicator formula) as follows:

```
length = input(200, "BB Len", minval=1)
mult = input(1.5, "BB STD", minval=0.001, maxval=50, type=input.float)


basis = sma(src, length)
dev = mult * stdev(src, length)

upper1 = basis + dev
lower1 = basis - dev
```

Based on this a problem arose because of two reasons:

First reason.

As I can see in the explain of the STDDEV function in talib, there are three parameters instead of the two you get in the pine script version:

1. inReal: the data serie
2. optInNbDev: Deviations, with a default value of 1
3. optInTimePeriod: Time Period, with a default value of 5 ( pine script does not have this )

Second reason.

As I noticed in the pine script reference in tradingview, it says that the stdev function is "a biased estimation of standard deviation.". I couldn't find any specific on this topic in the talib's doc, but I am assuming that they are applying the non-biased formula, based on some comments I found googleing here and there.

Based on this, do you think there would be a way to precisely replicate the tradingview behaviour using ta-lib?

Answer (score 3):

To remove all doubts, you can write your own function to calculate the standard deviation. I also had the experience of transferring to another platform and I needed a formula for calculating the standard deviation. Here is the result of my experiments.

```
//@version=4
study("Standard Deviation",shorttitle="Stdev")
length = input(14)

a = sma(pow(close,2),length)
b = pow(sum(close,length),2)/pow(length,2)
c = sqrt(a - b)

plot(c,title="Stdev",color=color.red,transp=0,linewidth=5)

plot(stdev(close,length),color=color.blue)
```

The values of the standard deviation of the built-in function are identical to those calculated independently.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of ta-lib as opensource is that you can look at sources and see what exactly it does. The stdev function sources are [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ta-lib/c/src/ta_func/ta_STDDEV.c#l219) and it refers to TA_VAR() function, which sources are [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ta-lib/c/src/ta_func/ta_VAR.c#l302).

According to my understanding TA-Lib's stddev is a rolling **biased** stddev of period `optInTimePeriod` that is multiplied by `optInNbDev`. So this function results in an array of stdevs made for each input array value considering subarray with length of `optInTimePeriod`.

There is no pine's stddev sources to compare, but it looks like you shall use `length` as `optInTimePeriod` and `mult` as `optInNbDev` (or leave it 1 and multiply values later). And expect the same results.

Comment: Turn out that the BB function in ta-lib is also biased, so it is pretty similar to the pine script counterpart, that being said, I made a few tests and the difference between the two in negligible, like 1-2 micro pips.